# how to Terminate program if user inputs invalid username and password several times

Tags: c#, sql

The problem in this code is that it doesn't terminate the program even though I clicked the login button with a invalid username and password 3 times. So what I want to happen is that when the user inputs a invalid username and password 3 times, it will terminate the program.

```
MessageBox.Show("Invalid username and/or password.");
pass_txt.Text = null;

int login_count = 0;
login_count = login_count + 1;
if (login_count == 3)
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Comment: and your code doesn't work ?
also why is SQL tagged ?

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint and looked at what is happening? Just by looking at the code you posted login_count will always be 1.

Comment: Hello, your code.. login_count will never be 3 as every time execute this code.. login_count is set to 0 then.. 1..and never be 3. That's why..

Comment: yes true just init the login_count somewhere outside this handler.

Comment: use login_count as global variable outside that code block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int login_count = 0;
login_count = login_count + 1;
```

Login_count will never be greater than 1, since you initialize it to 0 right before you increment it.  You need to make it global, then increment it without setting it back to 0.

You'll need something closer to

```
if(failedLogin)
{
    // ...
    this.login_count++;
}

// ...
if (this.login_count == 3)
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work.

```
    private void Login()
    {
        int login_count = 0;
        bool goodLogin = false;
        do
        {
            if (DoLogin())
                goodLogin = true;
            else
                login_count++;

        } while (login_count < 4 && !goodLogin);

        if (goodLogin)
        {
            //do the login stuff
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }

    private bool DoLogin()
    {
        if (true) //do the login logic here
            return true;
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid username and/or password.");
            pass_txt.Text = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
```